# PyCharm Docker Compose Debug Django

Tags: debugging, docker, pycharm, docker-compose, remote-debugging

I've followed Jetbrains tutorial for setting up Docker Compose with remote python interpreter on Mac OS

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/using-docker-compose-as-a-remote-interpreter.html#debug

Everything works well - starting and composing services, manage.py commands etc. apart from debugging. Pycharm just won't stop on specific breakpoint and prints in PyCharm status bar - "Waiting for connection"

Did anyone experienced same issue?

Comment: Please add your OS information also in the question

Comment: I have the same problem: PyCharm PyCharm 2018.1.3 (Professional Edition)
Build #PY-181.4892.64, built on May 15, 2018
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1136-b38 x86_64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
macOS 10.13.4
Docker 18.03.1

Comment: Linking your thread on JetBrains support site: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360000158764-Docker-Compose-Django-Debug

Answer (score 1):

This has happened to me, running `docker network prune` (to force docker to remap ips), then doing "invalidate cache and restart" has worked for me.