# PyCharm Docker-compose debugging

Tags: docker, debugging, docker-compose, pycharm

I have configured the python interpreter according to this instruction: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/using-docker-compose-as-a-remote-interpreter.html#docker-compose-remote

But the debug button for the docker-compose file is not available, I can only run the services as usual, without being able to run in debug mode. Why is this happening? Can I run the project through docker-compose in debug mode?

[image: The debug button is not available]

Comment: The linked documentation page does not mention "Debug" anywhere. What makes you think that the debug button should be enabled?

Comment: Have you seen [Remote Debugging with PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/remote-debugging-with-product.html) instruction?

Comment: Did you check similar questions on StackOverflow?  https://stackoverflow.com/q/49478352/1429387 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/49385861/1429387

Comment: If the provided links don't help you to solve the problem, please add more details. Show the docker-compose.yml file. I'm not an expert in Python, but I think it would be helpful for others to make sure that you are exposing the necessary ports for the debugger to attach to the process.

Comment: docker-compose.yml: https://pastebin.com/S8tfC9D5

How can I specify the ports to connect the debugger?

Comment: 1. Choose debug port (for example 5678). 2. Expose the debug port: add `- "5678:5678"` to the ports list of your `bot` service. 3. In PyCharm, create a remote debug configuration. Like described in [Remote Debugging with PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/remote-debugging-with-product.html), but set the host to `localhost` and the port to the one you chose (e.g., 5678). 4. Attach the debugger.